# Quadratic function problem

Tags: quadratics

[image]
Find the coordinate of point A in the figure Can you solve it in way which doesn't involve derivation?

Comment: 1. Compute the equation of the blue line. 2. Compute the coordinate of the second intersection point $P$ between the blue line and the red parabola. 3. Find an equation for the line (PA). 4. Conclude.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd solve it with derivation.  Just solve equations.  The y-intercept is -2, so the blue line is y = -x -2.  So the blue line intercepts the parabola when y= -x-2 =-x^2 + 4 so x^2-x -6=0 or x=3 and y=-5. so the equation of the perpendicular line is $y+5 = x-3$ then so A is where $0+5 = x -3$ or $(x,y) = (8,0)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parabola has zeros at $x=\pm 2$. Your blue line passes through $(-2,0)$ and $(0,-2)$ so its equation is $y=-x-2$. The blue line intersects the parabola a second time when $-(x+2) = -(x-2)(x+2)$ with $x\neq -2$, which occurs at $(3,-5)$. The black line is perpendicular to the blue one so it must have slope $1$. Therefore, its equation is $y = x-8$. So the point $A$, which is the $x-$intercept of the black line, must be $(8,0)$.

Comment: $(1,-3)$ isn't on the parabola...

Comment: @ChrisCuster Yes, I made a silly sign error. I've fixed it now. Thanks!

Comment: How can we find equation of black line using slope?

Comment: Do you know the formula $y-y_0 = m(x-x_0)$? We know the black line passes through $(3,-5)$, so just plug in $m=1$ and $(x_0,y_0) = (3,-5)$ to obtain $y-(-5) = x-3 \longrightarrow y = x - 8$.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: The coordinates of intersections between the parabola and the straight line are $(-2,0)$ and $(3,-5)$. Now apply the geometric mean theorem on the triangle formed by those two points and $A$.